# Ionic 2 - Error in ionic build ios - DomSanitizerImpl is not a StaticSymbol

Tags: angular, ionic2

I went to build my Ionic 2 project with `ionic build ios`, yet when I ran the command, I got this error, which I've never seen before:

`[11:47:55]  Error: parameters received {"filePath":"/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/bandly-app-mobile/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/src/security/dom_sanitization_service.d.ts","name":"DomSanitizerImpl"}
            which is not a StaticSymbol
[11:47:55]  ngc failed
[11:47:55]  ionic-app-script task: "build"
[11:47:55]  Error: Error`

It all started when I added the DomSanitizer to my project like so:

In my @NgModule file:

```
import { __platform_browser_private__ } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@NgModule({
   providers: [__platform_browser_private__.BROWSER_SANITIZATION_PROVIDERS]
});
```

And then in my component:

```
import { DomSanitizer} from '@angular/platform-browser';

constructor(
    public navCtrl: NavController,
    public navParams: NavParams,
    public sanitizer: DomSanitizer
  ) {
    this.videoId = navParams.data.id;
    this.videoUrl = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(`http://www.youtube.com/embed/${this.videoId}?rel=0`);
  }
```

I don't have this issue when I run `ionic serve`, only when I try to build it with `ionic build ios`. Any time what the problem here could be?

Comment: Import the browsermodule in to the ngmodule imports instead of just the service to the providers

Comment: I imported BrowserModule into my @NgModule file and it still gives me that same error when I run `ionic build ios` :/

Comment: Did you remove it from providers?